# jquery attr() method doesn't work but javascript version does

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is my current javascript code

```
var image = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('productVisu').getElementsByTagName('img').getAttribute('src');
```

This works in retrieving the URL attribute of an image. However when I try this jquery version:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var image = $('iframe').contents().find('.productVisu').$('img').attr('src');
```

I get the firefox error that this not a function. How do I resolve this issue and get the jquery version working?

Thanks

Comment: How are you referencing the jQuery library?

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` My other jquery functions work so I don't think this is a referencing error

Comment: What is `.find('.productVisu').$('img')` supposed to do? I don't think it does what you expect. jQuery objects don't have a `$` method.

Comment: Yes, `.find('.productVisu').$('img')` looks very wrong. Did you mean `.find('.productVisu img')` or maybe `.find('img.productVisu')` instead?

Comment: it's supposed to find class .productVisu and then find tag img and then return it's src attribute, tag img is the child of an 'a' tag of class productVisu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.productVisu').$('img').attr('src');
```

to:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.productVisu img').attr('src');
```

Comment: could you please explain how does this work, so in jquery if I wanted to find the img child of a class productVisu, I included it in the find functions parameter?

Comment: @jc.yin Compare the selectors to the type of selectors you would use in CSS. They're mostly the same.

Comment: It's always useful actually explaining what the problem is instead of just presenting a solution.

Comment: @jc.yin sorry, someone can have its own personal issues. Well, you called the selector again however, it is not valid. You can select elements just like you select elements in CSS. Here, you wanted to selected the `src` of `img` which was child of `.productVisu` so, using jQuery like that as you did will not work. You can just change your `.find()` method argument to first select the `.productVisu` and then its child `img` and get attribute of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your original code works, since `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return node lists, not individual nodes.

Try this instead:

```
var image = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector(".productVisu img").src;
```

Never use jQuery when you can use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/). It's like turning a screw with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Absolutely. Well, almost. IE7 didn't have `querySelector`, but unless you specifically have to support it I wouldn't worry too much about an obsolete browser that less than 0.66% of the Internet uses.

Comment: I'll give it a try then, the speed improvement looks amazing. But why do you say using jquery is like a sledgehammer? Haha is it that bad?

Comment: I made an [image](http://adamhaskell.net/img/jquery.png) explaining my opinion. jQuery is an overused tool that is horribly ineffective. I believe that anyone using it is too lazy to do things right.

Comment: haha omg I see why now. But I mean, for things like DOM, maybe it's cause I'm still a noob, but it looks like jquery's syntax is shorter and more compact than js version.

Comment: +1 for the vanilla solution and I suspect a download of vanilla.js is about to happen :-)

Comment: jQuery is 32Kb in size. That's a LOT longer than the space you "save" by writing `$("#elem")` instead of `document.getElementById("elem")`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need for the first two lines of code in your example.  You could easily do this:

```
var image = $('iframe').eq(0).find('.productVisu img').attr('src');
```